# List all special keys at runtime nsIProperties

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm trying to get a comprehensive list of all the special path keys. I found this here: [MDN :: nsIProperties - getKeys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIProperties#getKeys%28%29) but I can't figure out how to use it.

Like `XREExeF` in `Services.dirsvc.getService(Ci.nsIProperties).get('XREExeF', Ci.nsIFile).path`

These are the things I tried:

```
Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIProperties).getKeys()
```

then:

```
var cnt;
var oArr = [];Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIProperties).getKeys(cnt, oArr)
```

then

```
var keys = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIProperties).getKeys({})
```

All are erroring.

Comment: i did find this here: https://github.com/downthemall/downthemall-mirror/blob/c8fd56c464b2af6b8dc7ddee1f9bbe6e9f6e8382/modules/utils.js#L404 but makes no sense